# Getting a Bad Hour Error in crontab

Tags: cron

I am getting a **Bad Hour** error for the following crontab entry:

```
*/05 17-05 * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "http://abcd/cron/abcd"
```

Is there any issue with this? I want the cron to run from evening 5 PM to morning 5 AM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are not specifying which system you are using, I am hoping your system use a "Vixie" or "Vixie"-related crontab utility.

Still:

- `17-05`: is not considered a proper range (the lower limit being greater than the higher limit of the range).

You could instead write: "`17-23,00-05`"

From `man 5 crontab`:

```
 Ranges of numbers are allowed.  Ranges are two numbers separated with a
hyphen.  The specified range is inclusive.   For example, 8-11 for an
``hours'' entry specifies execution at hours 8, 9,  10 and 11.
```

So, sure nothing really forbiding you to write an interval the way you did.

The *Extensions* part of `man 5 crontab` is also interesting regarding how other crontab utilities would allow you specify more than a simple range (your system might be one of these):

```
 Lists and ranges are allowed to co-exist in the same field.
 "1-3,7-9" would be rejected by ATT or BSD cron -- they want to
see "1-3" or "7,8,9" ONLY.
```

So, as you can see, it really depends on your system crontab ability to understand what you mean by "`17-05`".

**For more information:**

- [man 5 crontab](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/5/crontab/) (the "vixie" cron)

Comment: but cron wont work for 1 hour between 11PM and 12AM right?

Comment: @Hacker it will work for those times as expected.

Comment: @Hacker: 11PM=23 and 12AM=0 ... so it will go up to 11:55PM and then go for 0:00, that is no stop